# dist-upgrade broke system: DEBUG package 'foo' produces an unwanted removal 'policykit-1-gnome', skipping

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 22.04, 21.10

Upgrading from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 LTS is taking a long time at 'cleaning up' /  'searching for obsolete packages'.
The log file `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` is spammed with

DEBUG package 'foo' produces an unwanted removal 'policykit-1-gnome', skipping

where foo are various packages.
[image: screenshot of log]

I did not find any meaningful discussion on Google that might bring up a solution or explanation.
The same issue was reported [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com&q=subject:%22%5C%5BBug%201874272%5C%5D%20Re%5C%3A%20Stage%20%5C%22searching%20for%20obsolete%20software%5C%22%20takes%20a%20very%20long%20time%20%5C%2830%20minutes%5C%29%22&o=newest&f=1) but for 'firefox-locale-en' instead of 'policykit-1-gnome'.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

I proceeded as recommended by `dist-upgrade` and ***my system broke completely***!
It seems as the skipped packages were removed and apparently some of them were essential. I could not even start in recovery mode. The only solution was to boot from a USB stick, grab my data from the disk and install Ubunutu from scratch!
I still have no idea why this happened...